# Remove word from end of URL using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have a bunch of URLs coming up as .../undefined which get a 404 error, and I'd like to know how to removed the word "undefined" from the end of the URL using .htaccess

I have looked at many posts about removing extensions, queries, and URL-internal folders, and have tried adapting those rules to suit my purposes, but so far I haven't been able to make it work. Any ideas?

Sample URL: http://www.theveggietable.com/blog/vegetarian-recipes/sandwiches/true-veggie-burgers/undefined

I just want the word "undefined" to be stripped out so that the user is automatically redirected to http://www.theveggietable.com/blog/vegetarian-recipes/sandwiches/true-veggie-burgers/

Thanks!

Comment: The code you gave me a few months ago works perfectly, thanks again! Now I need to modify it a tiny bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/undefined/?$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
```

or:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.*)/undefined/?$ /$1/
```

Comment: The first one didn't work, but the second did. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

redirect 301 should do the trick

redirect 301 /undefined http://www.theveggietable.com/blog/vegetarian-recipes/sandwiches/true-veggie-burgers/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `mod_rewrite` module in your .htaccess file to modify the URL. Although, it seems like you're doing something wrong in the back-end if you're getting those kinds of URL's. I would suggest looking into why you get `undefined` in the first place.

For more information on `mod_rewrite`, see [this blogpost](http://www.branded3.com/blogs/htaccess-mod_rewrite-ultimate-guide/).