# Remove string from some URLs with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

The code you gave me a few months ago at [Remove word from end of URL using htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19528834/remove-word-from-end-of-url-using-htaccess) works perfectly, thanks again! Now I need to modify it a tiny bit.

I have bad URLs coming up with /feed/ tacked onto the end. I want to use the same code to remove it, but this also messes up my actual feed URL. So I need to modify the code so that the only URLs from which "feed" is removed end in .html

For example, I need elearnspanishlanguage .com/grammar/verb/accidentalreflexive.html/feed/ to redirect to elearnspanishlanguage .com/grammar/verb/accidentalreflexive.html, but I need elearnenglishlanguage .com/blog/feed/ to be left alone.

Thanks in advance for any tips!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this additional rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+?\.html)/feed/$ /$1 [NC,L,R=301]
```

or using `RedirectMatch`:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.+?\.html)/feed/$ /$1
```

Comment: I used the second one but it left a trailing slash, so I changed it to RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.+?\.html)/feed/$ /$1 and now it works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: Yes good catch trailing slash should be removed. You can accept the answer now.